# Using Triggers to enforce constraints with two tables

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to create a trigger that ensures that any insert into the PC table does not have a model ID that already exists in the laptop table. I edited the statement a few times, but I keep getting Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER chk_models  
    BEFORE INSERT ON PC  
    FOR EACH ROW  
DECLARE  mcount :=0;  
BEGIN  
    SELECT COUNT(*)   
    INTO mcount   
        FROM PC  
        JOIN Laptop  
        ON :NEW.model=Laptop.model;  
    IF mcount!=0  
            THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20004, "Model Number Violation");  
    END IF;  
END;
```

Do you have any advice on how I might fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare variable `mcount`'s datatype and use single quotes for text. Also, the join is redundant, so I removed it.

This should work for you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER chk_models  
    BEFORE INSERT ON PC  
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  mcount int :=0;  
BEGIN  
    SELECT COUNT(*)   
    INTO mcount 
    from Laptop  
    where model = :NEW.model;  
    IF mcount!=0  
            THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20004, 'Model Number Violation');  
    END IF;  
END;
```